# Input desalinhado

Tags: javascript, html, input

Estou tentando fazer com que o campo desça e fique debaixo do outro campo como esta no modal. Bem, vou explicar melhor, eu tenho um formulário, nesse formulário tem o botão para adicionar filho, ao clicar é aberto um modal, se a pessoa tiver mais de um filho a pessoa clica em + (que chama o JavaScript).

O problema é que esta desalinhado eu até consegui fazer com que dois campos descesse porém não esta debaixo do outro campo, vou colocar a imagem.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
const add = document.getElementById("add");
const childrenContent = document.getElementById("content-children");
const formPersonalData = document.getElementById("formPersonalData");

function addNewInputChildren(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  let count = childrenContent.children.length;

  const section = document.createElement("section");

  // nome filho
  const DivNomeFilho = document.createElement("div");
  DivNomeFilho.className = "col-md-5";
  const LabelNomeFilho = document.createElement("label");
  LabelNomeFilho.setAttribute("for", "nome_filho" + count);
  LabelNomeFilho.innerHTML = "Nome do Filho";
  const InputNomeFilho = document.createElement("input");
  InputNomeFilho.setAttribute("type", "text");
  InputNomeFilho.setAttribute("class", "form-control");
  InputNomeFilho.setAttribute("id", "nome_filho" + count);
  InputNomeFilho.setAttribute("name", `nome_filho[${count}]`);
  DivNomeFilho.appendChild(LabelNomeFilho);
  DivNomeFilho.appendChild(InputNomeFilho);

  // data nascimento
  const DivDataNasc = document.createElement("div");
  DivDataNasc.className = "col-md-3";
  const LabelDataNasc = document.createElement("label");
  LabelDataNasc.setAttribute("for", "nasc_filho" + count + "BornDate");
  LabelDataNasc.innerHTML = "Data Nasc";
  const InputDataNasc = document.createElement("input");
  InputDataNasc.setAttribute("class", "form-control");
  InputDataNasc.setAttribute("type", "date");
  InputDataNasc.setAttribute("id", "nasc_filho" + count + "BornDate");
  InputDataNasc.setAttribute("name", `nome_filho[${count}]`);
  DivDataNasc.appendChild(LabelDataNasc);
  DivDataNasc.appendChild(InputDataNasc);

  // escolaridade
  const DivEscolaridade = document.createElement("div");
  DivEscolaridade.className = "col-md-4";
  const LabelEscolaridade = document.createElement("label");
  LabelEscolaridade.setAttribute("for", "escolaridade" + count);
  LabelEscolaridade.innerHTML = "Escolaridade";
  const SelectEscolaridade = document.createElement("select");
  SelectEscolaridade.setAttribute("select", "name");
  SelectEscolaridade.setAttribute("class", "form-control");
  SelectEscolaridade.setAttribute("id", "escolaridade" + count);
  SelectEscolaridade.setAttribute("name", `escolaridade[${count}]`);
  DivEscolaridade.appendChild(LabelEscolaridade);
  DivEscolaridade.appendChild(SelectEscolaridade);

  // dependente
  const DivDependente = document.createElement("div");
  DivDependente.className = "col-md-4";
  DivDependente.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<br></br>");
  DivDependente.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<br></br>");
  DivDependente.style.position = "relative";
  const LabelDependente = document.createElement("label");
  LabelDependente.setAttribute("for", "dependente" + count);
  LabelDependente.innerHTML = "Dependente";
  const SelectDependente = document.createElement("select");
  SelectDependente.setAttribute("select", "name");
  SelectDependente.setAttribute("class", "form-control");
  SelectDependente.setAttribute("id", "dependente" + count);
  SelectDependente.setAttribute("name", `dependente[${count}]`);
  DivDependente.appendChild(LabelDependente);
  DivDependente.appendChild(SelectDependente);

  // I.R.
  const DivFir = document.createElement("div");
  DivFir.className = "col-md-4";
  // DivFir.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<br></br>");
  // DivFir.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<br></br>");
  const LabelFir = document.createElement("label");
  LabelFir.setAttribute("for", "fir" + count);
  LabelFir.innerHTML = "Fins para I.R.:";
  const SelectFir = document.createElement("select");
  SelectFir.setAttribute("select", "name");
  SelectFir.setAttribute("class", "form-control");
  SelectFir.setAttribute("id", "fir" + count);
  SelectFir.setAttribute("name", `fir[${count}]`);
  DivFir.appendChild(LabelFir);
  DivFir.appendChild(SelectFir);

  [DivNomeFilho, DivDataNasc, DivEscolaridade, DivDependente, DivFir].map(
    (item) => {
      section.appendChild(item);
    }
  );
  section.style.cssText = "display:flex; flex-direction: row; width:100%;";
  childrenContent.appendChild(section);

  // dependente.style.cssText = "margin-left; 10px;";
  // childrenContent.appendChild(dependente);
}

add.addEventListener("click", addNewInputChildren);
```

```html
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Cadastro de Filhos</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                    </button>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body" id="content-children">
        <section class="content">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">

              <div class="col-md-5">
                <label for="son">Nome Filho</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="nome_filho[]" id="nome_filho" class="form-control">
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-3">
                <label for="nomefilho">Data Nasc</label><br>
                <input type="date" name="nasc_filho[]" class="form-control" id="escolaridade">
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-4">
                <label for="escolaridade">Escolaridade </label>
                <select name="escolaridade[]" class="form-control" id="escolaridade">
                  <option value="sel">Selecione</option>
                  <option value="2GC">Segundo Grau Completo</option>
                  <option value="2GI">Segundo Grau Incompleto</option>
                  <option value="CTC">Curso Técnico Completo</option>
                  <option value="CTI">Curso Técnico Incompleto</option>
                  <option value="NSC">Nível Superior Completo</option>
                  <option value="NSI">Nível Superior Incompleto</option>
                  <option value="PGC">Pós Graduação Completo</option>
                  <option value="PGI">Pós Graduação Incompleto</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section><br>

        <div>
          <section class="content">
            <div class="container-fluid">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <label for="dependente">Dependente: </label>
                  <select name="dependente" class="form-control" id="dependente">
                    <option value="">Selecione</option>
                    <option value="sim">SIM</option>
                    <option value="nao">NÃO</option>
                  </select>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <label for="fir">Fins para I.R.: </label>
                  <select name="fir" class="form-control" id="fir">
                    <option value="">Selecione</option>
                    <option value="sim">SIM</option>
                    <option value="nao">NÃO</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </section>
        </div><br>
      </div>

      <div class="row" style='margin-left: 1em;'>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Salvar</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Limpar</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" id="add">+</button>
        </div>
      </div><br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -4):

Idente o seu código antes de postar, e o JS não tem necessidade de estar aqui para resolver esse problema.

Vou tentar lhe dar uma dica pra resolver da forma que está:

A div da modal imagino que seja fixa ou absoluta, dentro dela crie uma outra div que servirá como um container para todo o conteúdo de sua modal, este container deve ter posição relativa e overflow hidden para evitar estouros de conteúdo como esse que está acontecendo na sua modal, após isso as suas divs que englobam os inputs devem estar todas com display inline block.

---

Agora as minhas sugestões de mudanças:

Recomendo muito que utilize Grid Layout para organizar melhor o conteúdo de sua modal ou de qualquer outra coisa no seu projeto (até dele como um todo), assim será muito difícil vc ter esse tipo de problema e não passará horas tentando "alinhar" elementos ou corrigir comportamentos inesperados, segue abaixo dois links ótimos com o básico do Grid Layout pra vc dar uma olhada com carinho:

https://www.origamid.com/projetos/css-grid-layout-guia-completo/

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).